# How do keyword arguments interact with model? Django

Tags: python, django

I have a question regarding the models in Django, specifically regarding how the attributes one specifies, such as: "author = models.CharField...", connect to the keyword arguments that are passed when creating instances of those same models.

A typical model that I am reading about can look like:

> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class MyModel(models.Model):
>    Attribute = models.CharField(max_length=100)
> ```

Then, when instantiating this and creating and object, what I see is frequently like this:

```
Instance = MyModel(Attribute='some text')
```

How do these connect? I know that the `__init__` in the parent class of my 'MyModel' takes kwargs - but I am not sure how it deals with them. How does Django make sure they connect to the Attribute that I have written? It kind of seems like I define an attribute in the model, and then try to redefine that same attribute when instantiating?

Thanks!

Comment: That is more or less correct: the model stores a list of fields, and the instances have attributes with the values stored for that field.

Comment: I have not been on SO for very long, and am not sure if this kind of re-commenting is alright, but will try. From reading the base.model code, it appears the first thing it does is 'strip' the key from each value within the kwargs dict, and save the actual new data for each field. (there is a comment in the code: '' Now we're left with the unprocessed fields that must come from keywords, or default''). I cannot seem to figure out how they later connect to the class-based attribute-fields that I have specified. Could you help me out?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I think the problem with this question is the word "connect". You seem to imply that these things have to connect in some way, even though they're different things. Exactly what do you mean by "connect"? Why should a class attribute have to "connect" with an instance attribute, beyond doing the appropriate assignments? You need to clarify what you're really asking for.

Comment: Otherwise, the simplest answer is that they're connected because they have the same name.

Comment: May have been a bit of a language mishap from my side. I have noticed that at times, the names of for example classes, such as the class Meta within a model, matter. It appears that sometimes, names help Django identify classes, and know how to deal with the information they provide. My initial thought was that that might have been the case here as well, but I am slowly realising that it is probably not the case in this instance, after the answer by @Basalex

Answer (score 3):

Django model fields becomes python descriptors. Let me explain a little bit how does it work. If you open your django shell you can write something like this

```
>>> from yourapp.models import MyModel
>>> MyModel.attribute
<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f67cf3449e8>
```

At the first look, you probably expected to see CharField instead of DeferredAttribute. Monkey patching is used here when the ModelBase meta class __ new __ method is executed (runtime) which has a code for registering all it's model fields and create descriptors based on them.

If you explore DeferredAttribute class you can easily find that this is  actually a nondata descriptor class because it has __ get __ method, and no __ set __ method. Absense of __ set __ method means - when you trying to set attribute:

```
instance.attrubute = 'some text'
```

it overflowed  by instance attribute now it actually is just a common instance attribute. And also DeferredAttribute class has the __ init __ method which is written below :

```
def __init__(self, field_name, model):
    self.field_name = field_name
```

As you can see it has a field_name attribute.

```
>>> MyModel.attribute.field_name
'attribute'
```

This name is used in __ get __ method for getting value from the MyModel instance (if it wasn't set it directly)

It's a quite a complex system, but I believe Django way of using fields is a great example of python descriptors and metaclasses power.

Comment: Alright, it's getting more clear for me. Would this be correct: Runtime, the code from the ModelBase meta class __ new __ recognises which attributes I have specified in my model, and creates DeferredAttribute instances (the descriptors off of them)? These descriptors are then able to fetch data from my MyModel instances, and these DeferredAttribute instances are later used when saving to the database? This would mean that the descriptors are accessing the kwargs entered for each MyModel instance, right? Thank you for a thorough reply!

Comment: Well, you understand it almost right, but not completly. I highly recommend you to play a little bit with the descriptors and see the diffrence between non-data and  data descriptors.  Descs are more much alike class-attrs.  Your model does't have to know that the field is a descriptor it only recieves the data from it. For example when python executes code like 'instance.attribute' - at first, it would try to find the attr in instance attrs and if no then python would try to look for it in class attrs, the same thing happens here.

Comment: In case of instance.attribute = 'some text', instance attribute called 'attribute' is created and no descriptor code is being executed. And when you later would try to access it would receive the data from instance attr not the descriptor. This is nondata descriptors behavior. And when the model is being saved it actually  has to worry only about the end data and not the way it was received.

Comment: Alright! Would this be correct: Runtime, there is code within class ModelBase that, through monkey patching, registers all the fields that I have specified through various attributes (such as 'author' =) and creates descriptors from these. Because of this, the fields are essentially descriptors, that can be accessed like attributes but really are objects with methods. When I create an instance of MyModel, and pass some kwargs with information for the database, the DeferredAttribute-objects - which are the 'field-descriptors' - deal with these kwargs. Once again, Thank you immensely!

Comment: Almost, but DeferredAttribute-objects (in case of non-related fields like CharFields) are used only for getting the data from db, not saving it. When you creating new instance of MyModel(attribute='some text') like this, attribute - is an instance attr and it shadows MyModel class-attr (descriptor). But if you would consider related descriptors (like ForeighKey), then what you`d just written is actually correct, because related descriptors are data descriptors and they have __ set __ method

Comment: This is still somewhat confusing. What exactly do you mean by 'it shadows'? Furthermore, when I write MyModel(author='abc'), author does not become an instance variable? It seems to be part of the kwargs dictionary, and dealt with through that. From what I have understood, descriptors are basically classes whose objects you can assign to attributes, that can manage data. What is unclear to me is how each field, each class-level descriptor, gets gets the information from the arguments? I.e, how does ''author = Charfield(...)( which becomes a descriptor)'' get the ''author = abc'' information?

Comment: MyModel(author='abc') - if author field was monkey-patched to non-data descriptor, there are two attributes exists now, one is instance attribute (author='abc') and the other is class-attr (author=Descriptor()), but instance attribute has higher priority then class-attr. So in case, of model.author you get 'abc', but if you 'del model.author' you would be able to get older value. Thats why you can set any non-related model field value to any data, even to list for example "model.balance = [1,2,3]" and it won`t fail even if balance is integer field, of course until you would try to save it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the model fields are *class-level* attributes. They don't actually have much to do with the keyword arguments at instantiation time; Django just iterates through the list of field names to assign the relevant values from kwargs. You can of course assign any attribute to an instance at any time, whether or not it has the same name as a class-level field definition.

It's only really when you save the model, or load one from the database, that the fields are used directly; Django uses them to determine how to save or load the data for each field.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Reading what you have written, there are a couple of things that confuse me. After adding some class-level attributes, such as "author = models.CharField...", what I have is basically: class Model, with all of its functionality, as well as the attributes that I have added.  You said that 'Django just iterates through the list of field names to assign the relevant values from kwargs', what do you mean by this? That Django recognises which class-level attributes that I have added? What does Django do with the kwargs dict that relates to the fields?

Comment: From reading the base.model code, it appears the first thing it does is 'strip' the key from each value within the kwargs dict (there is a comment: '' Now we're left with the unprocessed fields that *must* come from keywords, or default''), and save the actual new data for each field. I cannot seem to figure out how they later connect to the class-based attribute-fields that I have specified. Maybe that is within the ModelBase...